# Meaning of "it wasn't so much"

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

> **It wasn't so much that I wanted my sisters to be envious.** It was more that I wanted to celebrate my new privileges to come and go, to wander through shops without my sister's supervision.

What does this mean? Is there any alternate ways, synonyms, for better elaboration?

Answer (score 3):

> It wasn't so much [A], as it was [B]

This is a roundabout way to say, "It was more B than A".

The reason you might use this idiom is so to you can first say what something is *not* before you say what it *is*.  Usually this is in response to a statement that says or asks if A is true, or makes some kind of statement you want to negate.  For example:

> A: "I hear she doesn't like movies?"
>   B: "**It's not so much that** she doesn't like movies as she only likes movies with happy endings."
>
> A: "Is he religious?"
>   B: "**It's not so much that** *he* is religious as he was raised in a very religious family."
>
> A: "What time did the plane get in?"
>   B: "**It wasn't so much** what time it got *in* as what time they finally let the passengers *off*."

In your example the previous sentence would have explained something about the speaker's relationship to her sisters.  This is the response to that sentence, to clarify or to negate any possible misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

*Not so much X* means that *X* is less true (than some *Y*; *Y* is more true) or that *X* is not really the case.

> It is less true that I wanted my sisters to be envious (*X*). It is more true that I wanted to celebrate my new privileges (*Y*) ...

It is possible that it was mentioned (rumored, speculated, etc) that the speaker wanted *X*. Or, the speaker thinks that the audience thinks *X*. Instead, the speaker wants to clarify that *Y* is more true than *X*. It is possible that the speaker want *X* to a small degree, or that the speaker did not want *X* at all. You will have to judge for yourself.